# Are -er insults a British phenomenon?

Tags: british-english, offensive-language, pejorative-language

In the UK there are a lot of insulting words which end in -er, like this: scrubb**er** (slut), toss**er** (masturbator), chanc**er** (untrustworthy person), pooft**er** (homosexual), wank**er** (masturbator, generally despicable person), nutt**er** (insane), pos**er** (affected/overdressed person). I think it’s a relatively modern British phenomenon because it seems like American English doesn't have all these -er insults. Can anyone give any insight into this?

*(p.s. I am creating a plural tag "insults" since plural is winning votes over at meta.english.stackexchange.com; please [give your vote on whether tags should be plural or singular](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72/should-we-prefer-singular-or-plural-in-tags).)*

Comment: Bett-er late than nev-er to discov-er about this...

Comment: I think it's noteworthy that the -er is used here to create a verb, indicating that the insult is based on something someone *does* - i.e. their behavior.

Comment: @mickeyf:  How are any of the '-er' examples considered to be verbs?

Comment: I hear "poser" = wannabe used in the US not infrequently.

Comment: "Poser" is a corruption of "poseur" - but spelling it correctly is guaranteed to make you look like a poser.

Answer (score 6):

American English doesn't have *these* -er insults, but don't think it lacks -er insults all together. Wikipedia has [a list of pejoratives for people](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aPejorative_terms_for_people), and on the list I saw these -er examples that I'm familiar with.

- Ambulance chaser (scummy lawyers)
- Bible thumper
- Breeder (against straight people from gay people)
- Carpetbagger
- City slicker
- Cracker
- Holy roller
- Hoosier
- Loser
- Mother fucker
- Pecker

Comment: "Mother fucker" reads totally differently than "Motherfucker"

Comment: I want to note that *wanker* is one of the very small number of modern Britishisms that has made its way to some degree into ordinary American usage.

Comment: some others: *codger*, *greaser*, *hater*, *muckraker*, *poser*,   not to mention the “N-word”, which ends in *-er*.

Comment: Yes, most of these words are offensive to someone.  Take care when and if you use them.

Comment: @Cinque, are you really suggesting that even referencing the existence of an offensive word is in itself offensive?

Comment: @Cinque I’m going to give you the benefit of the doubt and assume you are not just trolling here—but by all appearances you are. If you think people can legitimately be offended by having a discussion about language and referencing the existence of an offensive word (without even mentioning it explicitly, and which, mind you, is completely relevant to the question of “insults ending in *-er*”), then you’re out of your mind. I would never actually use the word in question, but to pretend that it doesn’t exist in an intellectual conversation about language is, frankly, absurd.

Comment: @Cinque if you want to continue this discussion, I started a thread at meta: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/253/referencing-the-existence-of-words-that-may-be-offensive

Comment: @nohat: Is the "n-word" in the same category as these other "-er" words? Seems to me the other ones are "X-er, a person who does X", where doing X or being accused of doing X is insulting.

Comment: @Mr. Shiny I think it is in the same category as *cracker*, *nutter*, and *poofter*

Comment: @nohat But etymologically those words come from attaching *-er* to an existing word (see [*cracker*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cracker) and [*nutter*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nutter); *poofter* is presumably from [*poof*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=poof)). The Word Which Must Not Be Referenced gets its *r* from *negro*.

Comment: "Truther", "birther" and "deather" are recent ones.

Comment: @Jason Orenduff Actually, the Word Which Must Not Be Referenced is one who nigs (dresses a stone with a pick).

Answer (score 1):

I think mickeyf has hit the nail on the head here.  These insults end in -er because that is how you take a verb and turn it into a noun.  Like farm -> farmer, wank -> wanker, fuck -> fucker.  Probably the most likely reason you don't see many of the same -er insults is that the perjorative verbage in the UK is different than in the US.  Love the list, JoFrhwld!